# Creating a MySQL query that deals with calendar with multiple events

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to create a query that Produces:

```
VENUE | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-02 | 2012-10-03
 01   |  OCCUPIED  |   EMPTY    |  OCCUPIED
 02   |   EMPTY    |   EMPTY    |  OCCUPIED
 03   |  OCCUPIED  |   EMPTY    |   EMPTY
```

from these 2 tables:

Venue Table:

```
venue_id | venue
   1     |   01
   2     |   02
   3     |   03
```

Event Table:

```
event_id |    start   |    end     | venue_id
   1     | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-02 |    1
   2     | 2012-10-03 | 2012-10-04 |    1
   3     | 2012-10-03 | 2012-10-04 |    2
   4     | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-02 |    3
```

Could anyone suggest the best way of approaching this problem?

My current approach is:

```
SELECT 
   venue,
   IF(start <= '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-01' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY') AS '2012-10-01',
   IF(start <= '2012-10-02' AND '2012-10-02' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY') AS '2012-10-02',
   IF(start <= '2012-10-03' AND '2012-10-03' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY') AS '2012-10-03'
FROM Venue as v, Event as e
WHERE e.venue_id = v.venue_id
GROUP BY v.venue
```

However, I am not getting desired results... I'm getting the below instead:

```
VENUE | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-02 | 2012-10-03
 01   |  OCCUPIED  |   EMPTY    |   EMPTY
 02   |   EMPTY    |   EMPTY    |  OCCUPIED
 03   |  OCCUPIED  |   EMPTY    |   EMPTY
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mt. Schneider pointed out a flaw with my question. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weird thing is, your select statement doesn't even return the columns named as in the result set you posted. Also, i noticed you are repeating the day '2012-10-02' on your query.

```
SELECT 
   IF(start <= '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-01' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY') AS '2012-10-01',
   IF(start <= '2012-10-02' AND '2012-10-02' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY') AS '2012-10-02',
   IF(start <= '2012-10-03' AND '2012-10-03' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY') AS '2012-10-03'
FROM Venue as v, Event as e
WHERE e.venue_id = v.venue_id
GROUP BY v.venue
```

**EDIT:**

Both events bellow share the same venue_id and venue field, and your query is grouping by venue, this way its suppressing the OCCUPIED result on day '2012-10-03'.

```
event_id |    start   |    end     | venue_id
   1     | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-02 |    1
   2     | 2012-10-03 | 2012-10-04 |    1
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc33f/20

You could try adding an aggregate function like MAX to get any OCCUPIED occurrence contained on the subset of records:

```
SELECT e.*, v.venue,
   max(IF(start <= '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-01' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY')) AS '2012-10-01',
   max(IF(start <= '2012-10-02' AND '2012-10-02' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY')) AS '2012-10-02',
   max(IF(start <= '2012-10-03' AND '2012-10-03' < end, 'OCCUPIED','EMPTY')) AS '2012-10-03'
  from event e,
       venue v
where e.venue_id = v.venue_id
GROUP BY v.venue
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc33f/22

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I've edited the question. I'm still not getting the desired result though